# Prove that $f_n(x) = \frac{nx}{1+n^2x^2}$ is not uniformly convergent on any interval containing $0$.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of real valued functions defined by $$f_n(x) = \frac{nx}{1+n^2x^2}\ \text{for all}\ x\in \mathbb{R}$$ is not uniformly convergent on any interval containing $0$.

$\textbf{My attempt:}$ We see that $$\text{lim}_{n\to \infty} f_n(x) =\text{lim}_{n\to \infty} \frac{nx}{1+n^2x^2}= \text{lim}_{n\to \infty} \frac{\frac{x}{n}}{\frac{1}{n^2}+x^2} = 0$$ Hence the pointwise limit of $f_n (x)\to f(x)$, where $f(x)$ is defined by $f(x) = 0\ \text{for all}\ x$.

Let $0\in [a,b]$. Our aim is to prove that $f_n$ does not converge to $f$ uniformly on $[a,b]$. Assume $f_n \rightrightarrows f$ on $[a, b]$. Hence for each $\epsilon >0$ there exist a positive integer $N(\epsilon)$ such that $|f_n(x) - f(x)| <\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N(\epsilon)$ and $x\in [a,b]$.

Now choose $x =\frac{1}{n}$ $\color{red}{(\text{Can we choose? Why?)}}$ Then, $$|f_n(x)-f(x)| = \Big|\frac{nx}{1+n^2x^2} -0\Big| = \Big|\frac{nx}{1+n^2x^2}\Big| = \frac{1}{2}$$ If we take $\epsilon =\frac{1}{4}$, then  $f_n$ does not converge uniformly to $f$ on $[a,b]$.

Is my proof correct? Can you please advise me explicitly that why I can choose $x =\frac{1}{n}$. I am little bit confused about it.Thanks.

Comment: You can put $x=\frac 1 n$ but you should say $\text{sup}_{x \in [a,b]}\ |f_n(x)-f(x)| \geq \frac{1}{2}$ instead of $\text{sup}_{x \in [a,b]}\ |f_n(x)-f(x)| = \frac{1}{2}$. [The supremum is actually equal to $\frac  12$ in this case, but you haven't proved that).

Comment: @geetha290krm I have made changes in my proof. Is it correct now?

Comment: You need to make some specifications about $n$ in $x=\frac{1}{n}$. Let $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{m} \in [a,b]$ for all $m\ge N$ and then consider $x = \frac{1}{n}$ for a $n = \max\{N,N(\varepsilon)\}$. Since $|f_n(x)-f(x)| < \varepsilon$ has to hold for all $n \ge N(\varepsilon)$ and all $x \in [a,b]$, the $x$ you found gives a counterexample.

Comment: It is almost fine. Just say that you are choosing $n$ so large that $\frac 1 n$ is inside the interval you are considering. One more thing: If the interval is $[-r,0]$ then you will have to choose $x=-\frac 1n$ (with $n$ large enough).

Comment: Why to choose $x=1/n$? You can use AM-GM inequality, which gives $f_n(x)\leq nx/(2\cdot \sqrt{1\cdot n^2x^2})=1/2$ for $x>0$. The equality is when $1=n^2x^2$, i.e. $x=1/n$ (for $x>0$).

Comment: @mr_e_man Yes $0 \in [a,b]$.

Answer (score 0):

**Uniform Limits**

Assume the sequence is uniformly convergent. Then the restriction to the nonnegative axis is also uniformly convergent. The Uniform Limit Theorem says the uniform limit exists and is continuous.

Every uniform limit is also the pointwise limit. Hence (the restriction of) $f_n$ has a continuous pointwise limit.

However you can show (the restriction of) the sequence $f_n$ tends pointwise to $1/2$ times the indicator function  $f$ of $0$.

[image]

This function is not continuous. Contradiction.

Answer (score -1):

**Differentiate it**

It is enough to show the derivative:

1. . . .  is continuous away from zero.
2. . . . goes to infinity at zero.

Then you can find a suitable interval $[a,b]$ close to zero and use the mean value theorem to get $  |f(a)-f(b)| = |f'(c)||a-b|$. Show we can make $|f'(c)|$ big as we like by going close enough to the origin.

Comment: **How** does this show that $(f_n)$ does not converge uniformly???

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich You are right. I misread the question.